# How to install videowhisper video conference on red5 on centos?

Tags: centos, red5

I have problems to install videowhisper video conference on red5 on centos, i can't installed. Someone that have done this work can help me.

I have installed red5 1.0 on centos 6.6, ive tried to put the folder of vc_php of videowhisper video conference to the webapps folder of red5. I don't know if i 'am doing something wrong and also on my webapps folder i have another folder of videowhisper. when i put my 192.168.73.189:5080/vc_php/videowhisper_conference.swf it only stays on: entering video conference... verifying licence:Ok Logging in: and that's all i don't get more far and i reall want to install videowhisper video conference on red5

Comment: Could you let us know what problems have you encountered? Providing all the details that you can will increase the chances for someone who run into the same problems will see your question and help you.

Comment: I have installed red5 1.0 on centos 6.6, ive tried to put the folder of vc_php  of videowhisper video conference to the webapps folder of red5. I don't know if i 'am doing something wrong and also on my webapps folder i have another folder of videowhisper. when i put my http://192.168.73.189:5080/vc_php/videowhisper_conference.swf it only stays on: entering video conference... verifying licence:Ok  Logging in: and that's all i don't get more far and i reall want to install videowhisper video conference on red5

Comment: Please post these details into the question, that's the place most people look to.